# Contour Identification using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I have collection of objects in a image.
Check the sample input image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWuTW.jpg).

I would like to find the contour of each object.
I am following the below approach to identifying the contour using **OpenCV2**

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
dilate= cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
erode= cv2.erode(dilate, None, iterations=1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(erode, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

This is the contour output which I am getting for the above code : [see output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APdiE.jpg)

Is there any better approach for identifying the object in the image?

Comment: You can try [superpixel segmentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ximgproc/doc/superpixels.html) and select superpixels which have the [colour histogram](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d8/dc8/tutorial_histogram_comparison.html) similar to the apple "sure interior", and reject ones having the one similar to apple "sure exterior" which you can roughly detect with some preprocessing and thresholding. Automated way is [GrabCut algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html). To have better quality, search for neural networks for object semantic segmentation.

Comment: For example, in one of my early projects, I wrote the application, where I could fix incorrect superpixel segmentation with manually selecting/deselecting superpixels with mouse, and save resulting binary mask. After I had a hundred or so ground truth examples (image and binary mask), I trained pip2pix neural network with image as input and mask as output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed a simple step in your code snippet, `cv2.findContours()` works best on binary images, but you are simply passing the gray scale image to `cv2.findContours`. I have followed the following steps to segment out the apples from background:

### Step 1: Segment out the background which majorly contains gray-scale pixels.

You can use HSV color domain here, where low value of saturation would get the background segmented as:

```
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)

# Filter out low saturation values, which means gray-scale pixels(majorly in background)
bgd_mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([255, 30, 255]))
```

[image]

### Step 2: For pitch black pixels, the saturation value was abrupt so we segmented the extreme black and white pixels:

```
# Get a mask for pitch black pixel values
black_pixels_mask = cv2.inRange(img_bgr, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([70, 70, 70]))

# Get the mask for extreme white pixels.
white_pixels_mask = cv2.inRange(img_bgr, np.array([230, 230, 230]), np.array([255, 255, 255]))
```

[image: Black pixels mask]
[image: White pixels mask]

### Step 3: Merge these masks to get a final mask for `cv2.findContours`:

```
final_mask = cv2.max(bgd_mask, black_pixels_mask)
final_mask = cv2.min(final_mask, ~white_pixels_mask)
final_mask = ~final_mask
```

[image: Merged mask]

### Step 4: Now to fill in the holes, we erode and dilate the image:

```
final_mask = cv2.erode(final_mask, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
final_mask = cv2.dilate(final_mask, np.ones((5, 5), dtype=np.uint8))
```

[image]

### Step 5: Use `cv2.findContours()` to get the contours and filter them on area to remove the smaller ones:

```
# Now you can finally find contours.
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(final_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

final_contours = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > 2000:
        final_contours.append(contour)
```

### Step 6: Show the final contours

[image: Final output]

Here is full code snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_bgr = cv2.imread("/home/anmol/Downloads/tWuTW.jpg")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)

# Filter out low saturation values, which means gray-scale pixels(majorly in background)
bgd_mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([255, 30, 255]))

# Get a mask for pitch black pixel values
black_pixels_mask = cv2.inRange(img_bgr, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([70, 70, 70]))

# Get the mask for extreme white pixels.
white_pixels_mask = cv2.inRange(img_bgr, np.array([230, 230, 230]), np.array([255, 255, 255]))

final_mask = cv2.max(bgd_mask, black_pixels_mask)
final_mask = cv2.min(final_mask, ~white_pixels_mask)
final_mask = ~final_mask

final_mask = cv2.erode(final_mask, np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
final_mask = cv2.dilate(final_mask, np.ones((5, 5), dtype=np.uint8))

# Now you can finally find contours.
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(final_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

final_contours = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > 2000:
        final_contours.append(contour)


for i in xrange(len(final_contours)):
    img_bgr = cv2.drawContours(img_bgr, final_contours, i, np.array([50, 250, 50]), 4)


debug_img = img_bgr
debug_img = cv2.resize(debug_img, None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3)
cv2.imwrite("./out.png", debug_img)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked with another image but the detection of contour were not good. Can you help with this? For the reference check the input and output image : https://imgur.com/a/jG4Wb4r

Comment: I have just provided you with a starting point, obviously you would need to experiment with a lot of different images to get some generic values for this script, I have tuned the values for the given image only. You can take the concepts from here and tune the values as per your needs. The main takeaway is: Since your background is black in color, So try to segment it out first instead of segmenting the apples. You can also try with other color domains such as YCrCb, LAB, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try with other methods.